# Writing steps of the Bolzano Weierstrass theorem in logical formulas

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, quantifiers

> Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of elements of an interval
> $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$. Then there exists a point of accumulation
> $c$ of the sequence with $c\in[a,b]$.

The proof goes like this:

> Let $I_1=[a,b]$. Let $x_{n_1}\in I_1$. Let $c_1$ be the midpoint of
> $I_1$. Then $c_1$ separates the interval into $2$ intervals, each of
> leant $b-a/2$. **One of the two intervals must be such that $x_n$ lies
> in this interval for infinitely many $n$**...

How can I translate the bolded part into logical formulas? I think it should be
$$(\exists n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1})(\forall m\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq n})(x_m\in[a,c])\lor(\exists n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1})(\forall m\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq n})(x_m\in[c,b]).$$
Now let's say I want to prove the above disjunction by contradiction. The negation is
$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1})(\exists m\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq n})(x_m\not\in[a,c])\land(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1})(\exists m\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq n})(x_m\not\in[c,b]).$$
But I am not able to derive a contradiction from this. Have I translated the bolded statement correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is wrong. The assertion$$(\exists n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1})(\forall m\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq n})(x_m\in[a,c])\lor(\exists n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1})(\forall m\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq n})(x_m\in[c,b])$$means that every $x_m$ belongs to $[a,c]$ if $m$ is large enough or every $x_m$ belongs to $[a,c]$ if $m$ is large enough. That is not necessarily true. What is true is that$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N_{\geqslant1})(\exists m\in\Bbb N_{\geqslant n})(x_m\in[a,c])\vee(\forall n\in\Bbb N_{\geqslant1})(\exists m\in\Bbb N_{\geqslant n})(x_m\in[c,b]).$$Denying this means that$$(\exists n'\in\Bbb N_{\geqslant1})(\forall m\in\Bbb N_{\geqslant n'})(x_m\notin[a,c])\wedge(\exists n''\in\Bbb N_{\geqslant1})(\forall m\in\Bbb N_{\geqslant n''})(x_m\notin[c,b]),$$which is false; if such numbers $n'$ and $n''$ existed and if $n=\max\{n',n''\}$, then $x_n\notin[a,c]$ and $x_n\notin[c,b]$. But that's impossible, since $x_n\in[a,b]=[a,c]\cup[c,b]$.

Comment: Great thank you very much

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: I would just add a crude example here to paint a mental picture of a sequence that has a convergent subsequence but for which other elements bounce around (within the compact set of [a,b]), e.g. (3, 1.05, 7, 1.03, 2, 1.01, 6, 1.001, 3, 1.0001,...).  Not every element for large m is either in [0,1] or [1,7], but there is a subsequence that converges to 1.  I only mention it because I really like the B-W theorem.